# Data integration with Salesforce

Tags: api, integration, webservices

I'd like to integrate my client database with my Salesforce.

The main idea is once my client enters an account the same account to be integrated and visible into my Salesforce database system?

Is it feasible and how it can be achieved in Salesforce?

Also I'd like to know what information I have to request from the client before I begin the integration between the client's database and my Salesforce?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exact answer to your question is: **it depends**.

It depends on what you intend to do with the data on both systems. Is Salesforce going to be your primary system? The data will be available as read-only or is it required that Salesforce is able to update the data as well? Is it going to be real-time updates?

This is important because the integration between Salesforce and external databases can be achieved in different ways. If you want to be able to query external data like if it were in Salesforce, it is going to be expensive with [Salesforce Lightning Connect](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Lightning_Connect).

In case you just need Salesforce to be able to read the data, you can easily build a webservice in which Salesforce connects and retrieves the data you want. For example: when an user inserts an account on Salesforce, you would have a trigger that will fire up the connection, and Salesforce will send a "hey, do you have this account?" request to your endpoint, which will query the data on your client's database and return its data on the response to the Salesforce call. On the Salesforce side, when the call is returned with the account details, you can use this information to update the account record. This is possible if you want to update the external database, the same procedure would happen, but your external webservice would need to do the update on the client's database.

Now, if you want an external service to update Salesforce data, you will need to provide an user for that database, so it will be able to authenticate with Salesforce and insert/update the data. In this case you can either build a custom REST endpoint on your Salesforce org, or post the formatted data directly into the Account REST endpoint (which should be easier, in my opinion).

You need to know from your client:

1. Is he willing to pay for an expensive integration, if necessary?
2. Is he willing to pay for another license if he wants the external system to upsert Salesforce data?

If he doesn't want (1) then you won't use Lightning Connect.

If he doesn't want (2) then you will have to tell him that Salesforce will "take the initiative" regarding data modification (that is, Salesforce will always be the one connecting/requesting things to the external database).

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Lightning_Connect

https://developerforce.github.io/lightning-connect-tutorial/configure-data-source-objects.html

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_create.htm

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_rest_code_sample_basic.htm